# Did Hulk and Valkyrie have sexual relationship on Sakaar?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

I had an argument with a friend last night about relationship status between Hulk and Valkyrie. According to him, Valkyrie would give birth to Hulk's son [Skaar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skaar_(comics)) in *Infinity War* or further in MCU.

First, it looked funny to me because of [It's in my head now](https://youtu.be/jar9tQEiYVs) joke, but then I asked some other "MCU + Marvel Comics" fans. Interestingly, majority said it's obvious.

How is it obvious to lots of people? Did I miss something in the movie? Where did the movie hint about sexual relationship between Hulk and Valkyrie? I thought they were merely friends. Anything from words of god?

Comment: http://www.digitalspy.com/movies/thor/news/a841568/thor-ragnarok-tessa-thompson-clarifies-valkyrie-sexuality/

Answer (score 6):

While it's certainly *possible* that Hulk and Valkyrie were intimate during their stay on Sakaar, there's nothing in the movie that even hints at that.

The only interaction we see between them is very platonic. Tessa was the one who found Hulk on Sakaar and brought him to the Grandmaster, so she has a vested interested in training with him and keeping in the Grandmaster's good graces. The only other time she comes to his room, there was no indication that she did so regularly outside of training, nor was there any real hint of romanticism between them.

Indeed, the topic of Valkyrie's sexuality doesn't really come up at all in the movie one way or another. She's bisexual in the comics, which her character in the MCU [is as well](http://www.digitalspy.com/movies/thor/news/a841568/thor-ragnarok-tessa-thompson-clarifies-valkyrie-sexuality/), but the movie doesn't really explore that. At best we get some hints that she might have been in love with one of her fellow Valkyries that Hela killed.

For that matter, I don't think we get any real hint of *Hulk* being overtly sexual in that form. Presumably as champion it would be trivial for him to get "female company" in his room after a fight, but we see nothing like that.

---

In my opinion, I think it's pretty unlikely that Valkyrie is carrying Hulk's child, for a few reasons. It seems a bit racy for the largely PG-13 MCU, though that alone doesn't rule it out. More importantly, though, Marvel hasn't been focusing on Hulk for stand-alone story lines because of financial reasons, so I'm skeptical that they'd introduce his son into the MCU just to be a minor supporting character in other movies.

Comment: Ahh, yes, but _most_ secret relationships have no hint of romanticism ;-)

Comment: so what you're saying is that _everyone_ is in a secret relationship with _everyone else_? mind blown.

Comment: Point of correction. Most of everyone is in a secret relationship with most of everyone else.

Answer (score -3):

absolootly when she comes into the room and takes him down and starts to clime up on him, there's that kind on shy school boy smitten w/teacher thing untill she see's Thor.
Magiczombie